Toshiba 18TB HDD drive letter often disappeared
I have a Toshiba 18TB hard drive, model number MG09ACA18TE.
Recently, I found that it seems to be malfunctioning. Its capacity has been used up to about 90%, with only a little over 1TB of capacity remaining. I often encounter system freezes when reading files from it, and then the drive letter disappears. After restarting the computer, I can see the drive letter again, but the same issue occurs when I try to read some files again. I tried writing some files to the remaining space, and it worked fine.
Therefore, I suspect that there is a fault with the hard drive. I used DiskGenius to completely clear the sectors of the hard drive and then checked for any bad sectors, but there were no bad sectors found. So I wrote a program in Python to generate some 1.5GB files and write them to the hard drive. Initially, everything was fine, but when the hard drive was full and the last file prompted an error in Python, the drive letter disappeared again.
I am not sure if the hard drive has a hardware fault, and I do not want to continue using it to store my data. My hard drive is still under warranty, and I want to contact the manufacturer's after-sales service. However, I am not sure if they will be able to reproduce the issue once they receive the hard drive. If they only test for bad sectors using software like DiskGenius, they may not find the issue.
BTW, there also is a Toshiba MG09ACA16TE(16TB) HDD in this PC, but it works well.
So what should I do now? Can anyone offer some advice?

CPU: Intel Core i5-9600K
CPU cooler: unknown
Motherboard: Asus Prime B360
RAM: Kingston 16GB *4
SSD/HDD: Samsung EVO970 SSD 2TB/Toshiba MG09ACA18TE 18TB/Toshiba MG09ACA16TE 16TB
PSU: Golden Greatwall 650W
Chassis: unknown
OS: Windows 7 Professional 64bit
Monitor: Samsung 27 inch 2K


I did another test these days. I filled the hard disk with 1.5GB binary files, each is 1.5GB and wrote about 11,200 files, and then read them one by one. I tried it twice and didn't find any problems. Maybe I should just let this problem go and ignore it.
CrystalDiskInfo:




And, of note, your motherboard has official support for Windows 10 and 11 only. Running an old and obsolete OS like Windows 7 may play a part on the issue you're asking about, particularly if installed in Legacy ("BIOS") mode.

to  Joep van Steen: I used SATA 3.0 cable connected it to mainboard, file system is NTFS, partition mode is MBR, when I filled up my hard drive with Python programs, I switched to GPT mode.

to  ChanganAuto: Actually there are WIN10/WIN7/Ubuntu 22.04 in my PC, But I rarely use WIN10, because I have two display adapter and three monitors, and it is difficult  to correctly match resolution in WIN10(it is easy under WIN7), and my system has a lot of software installed, which has been running well for 4 years, and I don’t want to spend a lot of time reinstalling them in order to upgrade WIN10.

I also want to say that as a computer user who has been using DOS since 3.31, I have used XP for nearly ten years and WIN7 for more than ten years. I dislike WIN10 very much. It gave me a bad user experience. It is far worse than WIN7 except for the beautiful GUI. I use OS to run software on it. OS is just a platform, why do some WIN10 users feel superior to WIN7 users? I don't understand why someone deducted points from this post.

@SunJar - What does that have to do with your question? When a storage device disconnects, as you describe, it suggests a hardware issue. Have you checked if Windows is recording any sort of events when the drive unmounts?

To answer your question, you should backup your data and pursue warranty service.

@Ramhound No, no any hardware event in Windows log, for now, I cleared entire HDD so the I can't reproduce the issue again.

@music2myear The hard drive is still under warranty, but I know of a case where someone took a hard drive with a similar condition to Toshiba's after-sales service, but was told that the drive could not be repaired or replaced because no problems were detected.

That is frustrating and sad, but doesn't change the fact you should backup your data and begin warranty efforts.

I tested it three times in total, and all large files can be read correctly, but it takes longer to read the same location. I decided to continue using this hard drive and not contact customer service．BTW, The data has been backed up.
